# CA.pl file missing, how do I reinstall it?

Tags: gmail, postfix

I was recently trying to configure postfix with gmail. But a file called "CA.pl" is missing from `/usr/lib/ssl/misc/`. 
I tried out the command `/usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newca`, but, that did not work.

How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall the `openssl` package:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall --no-download openssl`

The `--no-download` switch is optional; I put it there because you should already have this deb in your local archives.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 the default directory for this file is `/usr/lib/ssl/misc/`.

In the other hand, you can get sure what package does provide this file by executing:

```
dpkg -S CA.pl
```

Comment: Actually, don't. `dpkg` will be able to identify the containing package even if the individual file itself has been deleted.